# I would like to create empty directory folders in a file path based on values in the list

Tags: for-loop, directory, python-3.3

I have my list

```
listnumbers='1.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,9.0,10.0'
```

I have my filepath

```
 filepath=r'C:\ArcGIS\Projects\Name'
```

I also have a for loop that attempts to take the values from listnumbers

```
for line in listnumbers:
  for value in line.split(','):
    os.makedirs(os.path.join(path,value))
```

though it creates the first empty folder which is 1, it does not create the following folder which would be 5.

Instead i get an error message that says

```
FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file  already exists : 'C:\ArcGIS\Projects\Name'
```

I need help. I feel I'am close and might need to make a small adjustment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is a bit weird... your `listnumbers` is not a list but a string, so when you do `for line in listnumbers:` the variable `line` runs over each character of `listnumbers`

This code works for me:

```
import os

listnumbers = '1.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,9.0,10.0'
folder_root = '/path/to/your/folder' # in your case: C:\ArcGIS\Projects\Name

folders = listnumbers.split(',')

for f in folders:
   os.makedirs(os.path.join(folder_root, f))
```